# Adding a char to a double in a output column

Tags: c++

I have a program that pulls in the First Name, Last Name, Hours Worked, and Payrate for an employee from a file. It then Computes the Gross Pay, a Tax Rate and Net Pay and then list the information on the console in columns(for now.)

What I want to know is can I add a '$' to the columns containing the dollar amounts, that are right aligned, and have the '$' right next to the amount. (like adding both of them to the same column.)

i.e. lastName, firstName, hours, $payrate, $grossPay, $netpay

I know if I LEFT align the columns with the dollar values it works like it was right next to it but then the decimal places aren't lined up and with them right aligned there is a column of '$' on by it's self.

This is what I have:

```
  Last Name   First Name  Hours         Rate     Gross       Net
1.Wingert       Antone      35       $   15.70 $  585.50 $  500.05
```

This is what I want:

```
   Last Name    First Name    Hours       Rate    Gross      Net
 1.Wingert     Antone         35        $51.70  $585.50  $500.05
```

I have 50 inputs from the file. It's for a class and we can't use anything we haven't talked about in class, so no printf and no arrays.

Comment: If you can't use `printf`, how are you aligning things presently? By hand? With `cout` and `iomanip`? As an aside, I hate this method of teaching. Heaven forbid you learn something before it's taught... Although it is admittedly a good idea to learn how things work at a lower level.

Comment: Convert the numbers to strings, concatenate them with `$`, and then output that in a right-aligned column.

Comment: @Cameron My guess is with `cout << '$' << setw(5) << right << rate`

Comment: @Cameron, Yes with `iomanip `.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AxSV.png)This is how I am doing it now.
    {cout << right<< setw(kCountSet) << count << "." << left <<          setw(kTableSet) << lastName  << setw(kTableSet) << firstName  << setw(kPayTable) << hours << right  << "$" << setw(kPayTable) << payRate  << " $" << setw(kPayTable) <<  gross << " $" << setw(kPayTable) <<  netPay <<   ends;}

Comment: I have no idea how to do code right on here, some one want to tell me?

Comment: In the editor, click on Code, to get the help for how to make code formatted.  (If it's not showing up, click the `?` at the top-right of the edit box, to make it appear.)

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the gotoxy() function to indicate where you want the '$' sign placed:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD pos={x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),pos);
}
```

Add this code in your file if your compiler doesn't have a gotoxy. You can find out more about gotoxy() online or try it out yourself.

If you want you can edit the code by creating your own function that can add any character at any position like this:

```
void addchar(int x, int y, char n)
{
    COORD pos={x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),pos);
    cout<<n;
}
```

Comment: No I can't, we haven't talked about that.

Comment: @jimistephen then just use the: 
 
     'cout<<'$ '<<rate<<'\t'<<'$'<<gross<<'\t'<<endl;'

Comment: The problem with that is I have 50 names, hours, and pay rates to deal with, doing that would not line them in columns down the whole console.

Comment: Another issue is I think these are windows-specific functions?

Comment: @jimistephen I don't understand what you mean? the \t will line them along the column perfectly. what '\t' basically does is goes to the nearest place on the console whose coordinate is a multiple of 8 horizontally. Give the \t a shot and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @AgneyaKoushik, does it align on the right or left?

Comment: @AgneyaKoushik, that didn't work either, I have numbers between 9.25ish to like 1500.00ish and using the "\t" would work great if all the numbers had the same amount of digits in them.